# jQuery prop function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML code:

```
    <ul class="expander-list" id="category">
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="filter"  class="checkbox0" value="all">
            all </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="electronics">
            Electronics </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="kitchen">
            Kitchen </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="decoratives">
            Decoratives / Interior </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="homedecor">
            Home Decor </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="furnitures">
            Furnitures </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="toys">
            Toys </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
          <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="filter"  class="checkbox1" value="vehicles">
            Vehicles </label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  startexecution:
  alert('checkbox is changed');
  var number = [];
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    number.push($(this).val());
  });
  if(number.length == 0){
    alert('now it zero');
    $('.checkbox1').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $('.checkbox0').prop('checked', this.checked);
  }
});
```

The following line is not working

```
    $('.checkbox1').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $('.checkbox0').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

if the size of an array number is 0 then it alerting 'now it zero' but the line of prop function is not working right now I am helpless so please help me for resolving this error.

Comment: For me it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/hgr1th17/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're code is intended to do. If `number.length==0`, then no boxes are checked. The `prop()` commands will proceed to uncheck all checkboxes even though they're already unchecked. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: check all checkbox if number.length == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `this.checked` refers to the state of the box you've clicked -- the one that fired the `change()` event. So `this.checked` will be `true` if you checked a checkbox and `false` if you unchecked a checkbox. Here's a demonstration:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  console.log(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="expander-list" id="category">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="all" name="filter" class="checkbox0" value="all">all</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="electronics">Electronics</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="kitchen">Kitchen</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="decoratives">Decoratives / Interior</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="homedecor">Home Decor</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="furnitures">Furnitures</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="toys">Toys</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="vehicles">Vehicles</label></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to check all the checkboxes, set the checked property to `true` rather than to the state of the changed box. Below, if your click results in zero boxes checked, all boxes will become checked.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
    $('.checkbox1,.checkbox0').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="expander-list" id="category">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="all" name="filter" class="checkbox0" value="all">all</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="electronics">Electronics</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="kitchen">Kitchen</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="decoratives">Decoratives / Interior</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="homedecor">Home Decor</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="furnitures">Furnitures</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="toys">Toys</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="checkbox1" value="vehicles">Vehicles</label></li>
</ul>
```